# EJS render parameters meaning

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');

var ejs = require('ejs'),
    people = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'],
    html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});

app.get('/' , function(req, res){
    res.render("basic",{html});
});

app.listen( 3000,function() {
    console.log(html);
 });
```

the "basic" is a basic.ejs file:

```
<html>
<title>Hello</title>
<body>
<%- html %>
</body>
</html>
```

This works but I want to know what exactly is going on in this line

```
html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});
```

What does the statement {people: people} do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{people: people}` puts the array of people, so `['geddy', 'neil', 'alex']` in an object, associated to the key `people`. So when EJS renders `<%= people.join(", "); %>`, it goes to the object that you passed to the function (`{people: people}`), looks for a key named `people` and uses the value that is associated.

Comment: so that can be renamed to anything! Thank you

Comment: Yes you could have `<%= foo.join(", "); %>` and pass the object `{ foo: bar }` where `bar = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex']`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can simply replace this:

```
html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});
```

with this:

```
html = people.join(", ");
```

The only difference is this

> <%= Outputs the value into the template **(HTML escaped)**

Since your array is safe, you don't need to use `<%=`

Comment: I think the question is more focused on the render parameter `{ people: people }` and how it relates to the template

Comment: @TheeSritabtim, I know, but to make it more clear that it's only a simple join done in the most horrific way. you don't want people to see such code and copy it blindly. someone have to simplify it.